# C# Backgroundworker & event based architecture

Tags: c#, events, backgroundworker

I'm trying to use a Backgroundworker in an event based architecture.

This is the backgroundworker creation code:

```
public void CalculateMetrics()
    {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true
        };

        bw.DoWork += CalculateMetricsASync;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += OnMetricsCalculated;
        bw.ProgressChanged += MetricsWorkerProgressChanged;

        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

CalculateMetricsASync:

```
private void CalculateMetricsASync(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        _feederMetrics = new ReplayFrameFeeder(_skeletonRecordingFilePath);
        _feederMetrics.FrameReady += MetricNewFrameReadyEventHandler;
        _feederMetrics.FeedFinished += MetricFeedFinishedEventHandler;

        _feederMetrics.Start();
    }
```

_feederMetrics is reading a file which holds information about Kinect skeleton frames, when a frame is ready, FrameReady should be fired and the following code should run.

MetricNewFrameReadyEventHandler:

```
private void MetricNewFrameReadyEventHandler(object sender, IEnumerable<Skeleton> skeletons)
    {
        foreach (IMetric metric in _metrics)
            metric.AddSkeletons(skeletons);
    }
```

But MetricNewFrameReadyEventHandler is never run.

I guess I'm only reading the file in the background. How can I use a backgroundworker to run MetricNewFrameReadyEventHandler in the background ?

Thank you

Comment: If you remove the `BackgroundWorker` from the equation, is `MetricNewFrameReadyEventHandler` ever invoked? Try running `CalculateMetricsASync` synchronously to make sure there isn't some other cause of the problem.

Comment: Actually it's not being run, even synchronously... I'm investigating...

Comment: BTW: note that you need to set `WorkerReportsProgress` to `true`